# backbone view events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, события

Начал знакомство с backbone с книги "Developing Backbone.js Applications" Addy Osmani. Там есть пример приложения, так вот, по нему не получается повесить функцию на клик по кнопке. При клике на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит, в консоли нет ошибок. Кнопка с `id="add"`.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Backbone tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="books">
    <form id="addBook" action="#">
        <div>
            <label for="coverImage">CoverImage:</label>
            <input id="coverImage" type="file" />
            <label for="title">Title: </label> <input id="title" type="text" />
            <label for="author">Author:</label> <input id="author" type="text"/>
            <label for="releaseDate">Release date: </label> <input id="releaseDate" type="text"/>
            <label for="keywords">Keywords:</label> <input id="keywords" type="text"/>
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">
    <img src="<%= coverImage %>" />
    <ul>
        <li> <%= title %></li>
        <li> <%= author %></li>
        <li> <%= releaseDate %></li>
        <li> <%= keywords %></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="delete"> Delete</button>
</script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/backbone.localstorage.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/book.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/library.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/book.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/library.js"></script>
<script src="js/routers/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

library.js

```
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#books',
    events: {
        'click #add':'addBook'
    },
    initialize: function( initialBooks) {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook);
        this.collection = new app.Library(initialBooks);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderBook(item);
        }, this );
    },
    renderBook: function(item) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(bookView.render().el);
    },
    addBook: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {};
        $('#addBook div').children('input').each(function(i, el){
            if($(el).val() != ''){
                formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
            }
        });
        this.collection.add(new app.Book(formData));
    }
});
```

подскажите пожалуйста, почему этот

```
events: {
        'click #add':'addBook'
    },
```

не срабатывает? Хотя подобным образом для book сделал событие delete, оно срабатывает прекрасно.

Comment: а где само создание главной вьюхи? `new app.LibraryView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не срабатывает render или сам клик? Если не срабатывает рендер, то ошибка в строках

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook);
this.collection = new app.Library(initialBooks);
```

Ты сначала включаешь прослушку события у коллекции, а потом коллекцию убиваешь. Надо так:

```js
    initialize: function( initialBooks) {
        this.collection = new app.Library(initialBooks);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook.bind(this));
        this.render();
    },
```